# Akka http memory leak with web socket

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a web server that accepts incoming websocket connection, implemented with akka http in Scala. However, I've been observing a monotonic increase in my app's memory usage. After some long digging, I found out that some internal Akka objects are created per every connection but do not get cleaned up after client disconnects. Specially, this class: `akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter`. One new such object gets created per connection. I used `jmap` to count the number of objects, command provided below. I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong here. Any advice would be much appreciated.

I have a super simple echo websocket server to replicate this observation:

```
package samples

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.{Message, TextMessage}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Source}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.io.StdIn

object AkkaWsExample {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  private val greeterWebSocketService = {
    Flow[Message]
      .collect {
        case tm: TextMessage =>
          println(s"Received $tm")
          TextMessage(Source.single("Hello ") ++ tm.textStream)
      }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //#websocket-routing
    val route =
      path("greeter") {
        get {
          handleWebSocketMessages(greeterWebSocketService)
        }
      }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)

    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine() // for the future transformations
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
  }
}
```

I then used any method to connect to this server and disconnect, and run jmap to count the object count, and notice a strictly 1 new object per connection. I tried it with thousands of connections as well, the same thing happens.

I used this command to count the number of objects:

> jmap -histo:live [pid] | grep ActorGraphInterpreter

Here's the results at startup and after opening and closing 1000 connections

> ip-192-168-30-10:~ liuh$ jps | grep Akka | awk '{print $1}' | xargs jmap -histo:live | grep ActorGraphInt | head -n1
>
> 701:             **1**             56  akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter
>
> ip-192-168-30-10:~ liuh$ jps | grep Akka | awk '{print $1}' | xargs jmap -histo:live | grep ActorGraphInt | head -n1
>
> 119:          **1001**          56056  akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter

You can see that the object count increased strictly by the number of connections. I made sure my client side is disconnected - I shut down the processes and also verified with `netstat` that the connections were shut down.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't take into account the fact that Scala is based on JVM which uses Garbage Collector which in turn is not deterministic. Particularly if you don't produce a enough of memory pressure (comparing to the allowed memory limit), the GC might not run at all. You can easily verify this theory by forcing GC (which is mostly probably bad in production but OK to debug things). Try adding to the start of your `main` method following code:

```
new Thread() {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    println("Start GC-thread")
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    while (true) {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      System.gc()
    }
  }
}.start()
```

This code starts an independent thread that will ask VM to do GC every second. I bet that with such code your test will not show more than a few alive `ActorGraphInterpreter` objects. At least this is what I see in your example. If you still see many `ActorGraphInterpreter` in your real code, your example is probably an inadequate [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you should post a better one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. jmap -histo:live actually forces a full GC. I figured out the issue. It's a bug within akka-http. The version I used was just one where this was introduced and not yet fixed. github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/2067

Comment: Hi. Which version are you using? I have the same problem

Comment: @user1861088, the last question is probably addressed to you